# Using express how to send blob object as response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, blob, truevault

Im using express and truevault to store images in my server. From the truevault api I get a blob object that looks like this

```
{ blob:
   Blob {
     [Symbol(type)]: 'image/png',
     [Symbol(buffer)]: <Buffer 89  ... > },
  contentType: 'image/png',
  fileName: 'image.png' }
}
```

How do I send this blob in the response object?

Answer (score 19):

A bit indirect but this will work:

```
res.type(blob.type)
blob.arrayBuffer().then((buf) => {
    res.send(Buffer.from(buf))
}
```