Having trouble loading a createObjectUrl() image in React
In my express/react project, I'm using the google places api to get city images. I send the image to the client as a blob, then use URL.createObjectURL(blob) to convert it into a url.
express:
    const photoReference = findPlaceData.candidates[0].photos[0].photo_reference;
    const photoOptions = { method: 'GET', headers: { accept: 'image/*' } };
    const photoUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=${encodeURIComponent(photoReference)}&key=${googlePlacesApiKey}&maxwidth=700&maxheight=700`;

    try {
      const photoResponse = await fetch(photoUrl, photoOptions);
      const photoData = await photoResponse.blob();
      res.send(photoData);
    }

react:
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:9000/googleplaces?query=${query}`);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch image');
        }
        const blob = await response.blob();
        console.log(blob);
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(url);
        setImageData(url);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      }


This is what the console.log's return:

When I assign it as an image property in React, it fails to load. This is what firefox shows: 
I've tested the google places API and can confirm it returns images correctly. I've tried setting it as the src property in an img tag but that also doesn't work. When I visit the blob link, it returns an empty JSON ({}).

Hi, While sending it from Express, it may be need to take care as this post says - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665103/using-express-how-to-send-blob-object-as-response
